# What is the meaning of the auth parameter to FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I want to ask question about the [FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/manage-users):

> public abstract void onAuthStateChanged (FirebaseAuth auth)
>
> This method gets invoked in the UI thread on changes in the
>   authentication state:
>
> - Right after the listener has been registered
> - When a user is signed in
> - When the current user is signed out
> - When the current user changes
> - When there is a change in the current user's token
>
> Parameters
>
> **auth** - use it to desambiguate which FirebaseAuth instance the event
>   corresponds to, in the case where you are using more than one at the
>   same time

Can someone explain this in a use case maybe?
**"auth use it to desambiguate which FirebaseAuth instance the event corresponds to, in the case where you are using more than one at the same time"**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have multiple `FirebaseApp` instances in a single application, you'd have multiple instances of `FirebaseAuth` too. If you'd use a single listener to detect auth state changes on both instances, you can then use the `auth` parameter to determine which one fired.

Comment: Thanks @puff always spot on. .Add that "text" to the docs maybe and you have a few more car mechanics doing Firebase